# Erratic Response Times for Thrift Client/Server After Idle Periods

Tags: java, sockets, thrift

I've written a simple Thrift client and server to test a service.  I'm using the simplest client I can find...

```
TSocket socket = new TSocket(<host here>, 8002);
TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(socket);
Facade.Client client = new Facade.Client(proto);
socket.open();
...
```

...and the simplest server...

```
Facade.Iface implementation = facadeContext.getBean(Facade.Iface.class);
Facade.Processor processor = new Facade.Processor(implementation);
TServerTransport transport = facadeContext.getBean(TServerSocket.class);  
final TServer thriftServer = new TSimpleServer(new Args(transport).processor(processor));
thriftServer.serve();
...
```

(Also, everything in the environment is Thrift 0.6.1.)

When I rip off a couple hundred requests with this client, response times settle around 2 ms, which is fine in my context.  However, if I continue to make requests, but place a slight delay in between them, let's say, 5 seconds, these times spike up to 4-6 ms.

I've played around with the Socket keep-alive properties and some other things, but there is some overhead going on that I can't seem to quantify.  Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: And if you close the socket after a request and open it again for a new call is it better?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple TCP server using plain java.io.Socket and I think what I'm seeing above has nothing to do with Thrift.  I think the slight delay I observed had to do with the fact that a burst of requests buffers input from those requests at the server, while intermittent requests don't get that benefit.  Specifically, in the code below...

```
public class SocketServerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8002)) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine = null;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine.equals("ping")) { out.println("pong"); }
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

...in.readLine() doesn't block when there is request data buffered.

Now, this alone doesn't account for a 2 ms delay, but there are a couple places where the above sequence is happening, so it adds up.